# cannot create disk image of Windows disk because of small FAT32 partition at front of drive

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning, backup

I'm currently trying to backup a disk image of a recent Windows7 installation that I have, but the Backup & Restore----->Create System Image is not allowing it because there is a small FAT32 partition at front of drive.

[image]

The machine is dual booted, with an Ubuntu installation on a separate 48.83 GB partition (this is why there is a 512 MB Fat32 partition in the front of all partitions which serves as a boot loader). The reason Windows7 will not back this partition up is because the format is not NTFS (Windows7 seems to require this), however I was not given the option to deselect this partition in the Backup & Restore wizard, therefore I can not make a system image.

I tried using Clonezilla for the operation but it dint quite work (I was successful at cloning the drive, however it would not load because the hardware configuration is different).

Does anyone know how I might go about making a system backup?